# Trouble with joining tables on BigQuery

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, google-ads-data-hub

I managed to join two tables together on BigQuery, however, I don't think it matches correctly. `clients` have descriptive client names with 75 rows, while `stats` contain client stats with 37342 rows. I'm trying to join these two tables together using their `ExternalCustomerId` with this query:

```
SELECT 
clients.AccountDescriptiveName AS client_name,
stats.ExternalCustomerId AS client_id,
AverageCost,
AverageCpc,
AverageCpm,
AveragePosition
FROM `298114322003.google_ads1.p_Customer_2670156874` AS clients
JOIN `298114322003.google_ads1.p_AccountStats_2670156874` AS stats
ON clients.ExternalCustomerId = stats.ExternalCustomerId
```

However, the results came out to *113026* rows. I expect the results to be 37342 since that's the results of the `stats` table. I've used `RIGHT/LEFT JOIN` function and it still came out the same. Any suggestions on how I should tackle this problem? Thank you!

AK

Comment: Well the query you posted above is already using an inner join, which is _more_ restrictive than an outer join.  This means that switching to a left or right join could only result in _more_ records than 37,342 in the result set.

Comment: Your sql has no issues so this is almost definitely an issue with your assumptions about your data. I suspect that the `ExternalCustomerID` is not unique in either table and so you are getting a sort of cartesian product. Post some sample data and your desired results and we can probably help out more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your `stats` table has mutiple rows for the same `ExternalCustomerId` (and it can be understandable for example if it is partitioned and you have different data during the days).

Try to explore a little bit more as it follows:

```
SELECT count(*) as total, count(distinct ExternalCustomerId) as uniques
FROM `298114322003.google_ads1.p_AccountStats_2670156874`
```

If you have duplicated `ExternalCustomerId` then every client row will be multiplied by the number of matching rows in the `stats` table.

Comment: Thanks for the info! This was def helpful, cause after discussing with our SEM manager, we have a few inactive clients but they still have a Google Ads account just in case they want to reactivate it back – hence the inactive IDs are still recorded, and no data is shown. Will look more into this. Again, thank you.